# variance in performance of very simple programs

Tags: optimization

I've written a very simple C program to demonstrate something I'm seeing with a more complex program that I am trying to optimize. Here's the simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t loops = 0;
    uint64_t count;

    if (argc > 1) {
        if (sscanf(argv[1], "%" SCNx64, &loops) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid loops %s\n", argv[1]);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    printf("loops = %" PRIx64 "\n", loops);
    for (count = 0; count < loops; ++count) {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

So now I run it a few times on my ubuntu 20.04 lenovo laptop using the same number of loops and the date and time commands to measure how long it takes to execute:

```
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~/opengl/matrix_code/timing$ date; time ./a.out 1000000000; date
Tue 11 May 2021 06:21:51 PM PDT
loops = 1000000000

real    2m15.489s
user    2m15.433s
sys 0m0.004s
Tue 11 May 2021 06:24:07 PM PDT
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~/opengl/matrix_code/timing$ date; time ./a.out 1000000000; date
Tue 11 May 2021 06:25:56 PM PDT
loops = 1000000000

real    2m7.822s
user    2m7.792s
sys 0m0.001s
Tue 11 May 2021 06:28:04 PM PDT
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~/opengl/matrix_code/timing$
```

I'd expect such a simple program to execute in closer to constant time, yet as can be seen there's a 5% difference in execution time. In my more complex program, the variance is much larger, despite the fact that it is doing no I/O. It allocates memory, does a bunch of integer and double float math and frees memory. That's it.

Is there something I can do to get these numbers more consistent. I was hoping to rely on differences in these timings to determine if optimizations I am doing have the desired effect, but if the exact same code with the exact same data varies so much, my optimization efforts will be blinded by this noise.

Or perhaps I can use some other strategy?

## Thanks

Update of 5-12-2021

Doug Smythies, in response to your query about more info on the CPU, is this sufficient?

```
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 763.853
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 800.081
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 752.384
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 800.383
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 4
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 719.028
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 5
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 772.575
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 6
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 800.224
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 762.521
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest ple pml ept_mode_based_exec
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$
```

Doug, the numbers you report on your server are more in line with what I expected to see on my laptop. Our processors are not quite the same model but both are Intel i5s.

Update 5-13-2021:

Doug, I installed linux-tools-common as suggested but get an error when I run turbostat:

```
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$ which turbostat
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$ sudo apt install linux-tools-common
[sudo] password for jeff: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm10 python3-pyxattr
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 217 kB of archives.
After this operation, 687 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-tools-common all 5.4.0-73.82 [217 kB]
Fetched 217 kB in 1s (395 kB/s)            
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-common.
(Reading database ... 200137 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_5.4.0-73.82_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.4.0-73.82) ...
Setting up linux-tools-common (5.4.0-73.82) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$ which turbostat
/usr/bin/turbostat
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt --interval 15
WARNING: turbostat not found for kernel 5.8.0-53

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.8.0-53-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-5.8.0-53-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generic
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$
```

When I google the text of that WARNING I find references from people who followed the suggestions provided by turbostat and then ran into more problems that included broken dependencies.

Suggestions as to the least risky thing to try much appreciated. 8^)

Update of 5-14-2021:

Doug, you wrote:

```
for your turbostat troubles see this bug report. Just by-pass the annoying wrapper and run it directly. Are you up to date with everything? you seem to be running the kernel for the hwe version whereas linux -tools-common expects the non-hwe kernel. – Doug Smythies 20 hours ago
installing linux-tools-5.8.0-53-generic should help and yet not break other dependencies. Note that I don't do it this way, I use the master turbostat as compiled directly from the master kernel source tree. – Doug Smythies 7 hours ago
```

I looked at that script and couldn't figure out any way to run turbostat directly. It doesn't appear that the package actually installs an executable named turbostat other than the script. In any case, rather than fumble through this turbostat installation problem I decide to just poke a 0 into that sysfs noturbo entry like you suggested, like so:

```
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
0
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~$
```

And that worked perfectly! Now execution times, though slower as you predicted, are consistent (at least much more consistent than before):

```
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~/opengl/matrix_code/timing$ date; time ./a.out 1000000000; date
Fri 14 May 2021 01:51:47 PM PDT
loops = 1000000000

real    4m7.149s
user    4m7.122s
sys 0m0.000s
Fri 14 May 2021 01:55:54 PM PDT
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~/opengl/matrix_code/timing$ date; time ./a.out 1000000000; date
Fri 14 May 2021 01:55:59 PM PDT
loops = 1000000000

real    4m6.895s
user    4m6.882s
sys 0m0.001s
Fri 14 May 2021 02:00:06 PM PDT
jeff@jeff-ThinkPad-E15:~/opengl/matrix_code/timing$
```

As to your question about the hwe kernel, I installed this by downloading what was then the latest stable version of ubuntu 20.04 LTS ISO, putting it on a flash drive and installing it from the flash drive on top of the Windows that came with the laptop. If that results in the installation of a hwe kernel, its news to me. 8^)

Thanks a bunch! You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Run it 100 times in a loop; time that. Performance analysis is complex. Which shared libraries had to be loaded the first time, but not the second. 100 executions will even out the startup delay. 100, 1000, ...

Comment: Modern processors do not always hold at the same CPU frequency when busy. Often the frequency will change as a function of other active cores and/or because of CPU migration. We would need to know more about your hardware, in particular your processor make and model, to be able to comment further.

Comment: Out of interest I ran your program on my test server: 1m23.142s; 1m23.235s; 1m23.237s. Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10600K CPU @ 4.10GHz, 4.8GHz max, no matter how many active cores. Otherwise completely idle.

Comment: for your turbostat troubles see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1844201). Just by-pass the annoying wrapper and run it directly. Are you up to date with everything? you seem to be running the kernel for the hwe version whereas linux -tools-common expects the non-hwe kernel.

Comment: installing `linux-tools-5.8.0-53-generic` should help and yet not break other dependencies. Note that I don't do it this way, I use the master turbostat as compiled directly from the master kernel source tree.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor, being a mobile model, has a low TDP of 15 watts. It is likely that the CPU frequency for your 100% load is not constant. It may be throttling down for a number of reasons: Multiple active cores; Power limits; Thermal limits; ...

To be able to proceed with your work and to be able to ensure that run to run variability is only due to your code changes/optimizations, you need to first find a stable operating point for your testing. You need to limit the maximum CPU frequency to less than or equal to the point where the system will not throttle it lower for any reason.

The recommended monitoring tool for this is turbostat (included in the linux-tools-common) package). Additionally, although it might not make any difference, your example program is single threaded so try forcing CPU affinity. Example (I have called your program `ask.c` and compile it to `ask`):

```
doug@s19:~/tmp$ time taskset -c 5 ./ask 1000000000
loops = 1000000000

real    1m23.237s
user    1m23.236s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Meanwhile, `turbostat` was running:

```
doug@s19:~$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt --interval 15
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
0.01    1224    446     36      1.36    0.00    0.89
0.01    800     354     35      1.36    0.00    0.89
4.30    4790    8122    48      12.20   0.00    0.89
8.32    4800    15430   48      22.49   0.00    0.89
8.32    4800    15358   48      22.60   0.00    0.89
8.32    4800    15377   48      22.63   0.00    0.89
8.32    4800    15394   48      22.58   0.00    0.89
8.32    4800    15435   49      22.61   0.00    0.89
0.23    4634    758     36      2.04    0.00    0.89
0.01    800     348     36      1.47    0.00    0.89
```

Notice the CPU frequency is steady at 4.8 GHz during the time the program runs, and is also nowhere near any other limit that might cause throttling. Run `turobstat` without the `--quiet` option to know some of those limits:

```
...
cpu8: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x303030303030
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 6 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 5 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
...
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x000003e8 (125 W TDP, RAPL 0 - 0 W, 0.000000 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x428440001b83e8 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (125.000000 Watts, 8.000000 sec, clamp ENabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: ENabled (136.000000 Watts, 0.002441* sec, clamp DISabled)
```

A suggested starting point for you is just disable turbo. You should be using the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver by default, so:

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
```

And `turbostat`:

```
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
8.32    4100    15613   39      13.04   0.00    0.89
8.32    4100    15386   39      13.12   0.00    0.89
8.32    4100    15382   39      13.02   0.00    0.89
8.32    4100    15384   40      13.05   0.00    0.89
```

Notice the significant power drop. And the program takes longer, of course:

```
doug@s19:~/tmp$ time taskset -c 5 ./ask 1000000000
loops = 1000000000

real    1m37.531s
user    1m37.531s
sys     0m0.003s
```

To just limit CPU frequency directly, do, and for example:

```
doug@s19:~/tmp$ echo 95 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
95
```

`turbostat` during program (obviously, I re-enabled turbo):

```
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
0.02    1266    694     34      1.69    0.00    0.89
0.03    800     681     34      1.39    0.00    0.89
1.70    4553    3662    44      5.01    0.00    0.89
8.32    4600    15387   44      19.24   0.00    0.89
8.32    4600    15374   44      19.46   0.00    0.89
```